# Reading unflushed page from another process

Tags: c++, linux, mmap, producer-consumer

I have a producer process, that writes to a mmap'd file and a consumer process that reads from it.  This is on Linux.

If the producer makes a change to the mmap and its not instantly flushed, when the consumer access it what happens?  Will it get the old version from the disk, or is it clever enough to get the unflushed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`mmap()` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap):

> MAP_SHARED
>
> Share this mapping with all other processes that map this object.
>   Storing to the region is equivalent to
>   writing to the file. The file may not
>   actually be updated until msync(2) or
>   munmap(2) are called.

Bottom line: changes will be immediately visible to other processes if you specify so when calling `mmap()`. According to the documentation you *have* to use either `MAP_SHARED` or `MAP_PRIVATE`, which controls the behaviour with regard to other processes mapping the same file area.

Comment: So while changes between processes are immediately propagated, the disk may not actually receive the change until later or when you call `msync`.